# Has anyone used Sigma Grid (Javascript-based editable data grid)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, grid, data-entry, sigma-grid-control

Has anyone here used [Sigma Grid](http://www.sigmawidgets.com/products/sigma_grid2/) for JavaScript-based data grids?  It was the only grid I could find that would allow fast data entry and use of the keypad, but before we spend a lot of development time I wanted to learn about the community's experience with it.

(Note:  we need dozens of fast, sortable, and editable grids that can be used with the arrow keys and minimal mouse use ... otherwise we'd just pop in an ASP.NET control)

Comment: https://jsgrids.io/ is a list of JavaScript grid libraries. You might be able to use the "accessible" filter to determine whether or not a library is keyboard-accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We decided to go with Sigma Grid after the folks at the other ASP.NET control companies said they couldn't provide the required functionality.

Answer (score 1):

it is a good dat grid to use over desktop and web..
it is light weight and very efficient,but the problem is very little help found on internet regarding sigma data.
before starting implementing grid,you must read its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I've used it at my previous job and it's highly customizable, full of features, and relatively quick to use. It's really got everything your grid needs

Be warned though, there is very minimal documentation available for it, and it takes TIME to develop customizations thanks to the documentation. The support forums are also slow.

If you dont find another grid which is suitable, then only would i suggest using this grid.

Answer (score 0):

Sigma Ajax Grid is a good tool and you can use in your project. I would also recommend you - dhtmlGrid(www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/)

Comment: Thanks, we looked at dhtmlGrid but the keyboard-only data entry was lacking (i.e. you couldn't easily use arrow/enter keys to type blindly).

Comment: There are separate key maps for the dhtlmxgrid, one of which provides necessary functionality

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/navigation/pro_keymap_excel.html